# Can't import Large PNG-Animations into Flash CS5.5

Tags: flash, import, out-of-memory

Im trying to import a large png-animation into my flash cs5.5 project and get the following warning...

THE IMPORT DIDNT FINISH BECAUSE AN UNKNOW ERROR OCURED

I opened the activity monitor to see how mach ram is used when i do that, and it went all the way up to 4GB - which was my limit. So i upgraded my macbook to 16GB, but it still doesn't work. When i look at the activity monitor, I'm still only using 4GB of my now 16GB.

However, I CAN import the same animation into a new project, but if i COPY FRAMES and PASTE into my actual project, I get an error message again.

I tried to increase publish cache - with no luck.
And i remember about a year ago i changed a number somewhere so that i can publish large action scripts - but i don't remember how i did that back then.

Any idea how this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the setting you were talking about: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/large-flash-applications-compile-incorrectly.html